# How to turn off Firefox address bar auto-selection on focus

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

If you're typing in the Firefox address bar and <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to a different window, then  back, the entire text in the address bar is highlighted.  This is extremely annoying to me.  Is there a way to turn this behavior off?  What I'd like to see is whatever I had when I left the application (e.g. either a selection or an insert point).  My Firefox version is 3.5.3, if that matters.  Thanks!

Comment: There’s a closely related issue about the _click_ behavior which I addressed here: [go back to NOT selecting the whole URL when i click the address bar](https://superuser.com/a/1559926/751213).

Comment: see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1849593

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Modern answer:**

My Linux systems no longer highight the Awesome bar contents when returning from Alt-Tab, so (for me) there's no need for this tweak of a config parameter that no longer exists.

For everyone else, apparently this will not be fixed:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1849593

**OLD ANSWER FROM 2009:**
From [About:Config Tweaks For Firefox 3](http://www.pctipsbox.com/aboutconfig-tweaks-for-firefox-3/)

(First type about:config in your location field)

> 18. Enable/Disable Single Click to
>     Select Whole URL in Address bar
>
> To Enable Single Click Select URL of
> address bar use the below about:config
> Tweak
>
> ```
> browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll = True
> ```
>
> To disable Single Click Select
>
> ```
> browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll = False
> ```