# Go back to NOT selecting the whole URL when I click the address bar

Tags: firefox, browser, address-bar

Recently every browser changed its URL bar behaviour. When you click into the address bar, it selects the whole URL.

I’m a web developer, so most of the time I just want to edit a parameter in the URL or add to it. This auto-selection behaviour is painful. I aim my pointer exactly where I want the cursor to be, click it, and the whole URI is selected, so as soon as I start to type, everything gets deleted.

Is there any way to revert the “`clickSelectsAll`” behavior on Firefox?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Firefox, March 2020 and later

Around March 2020, the [`browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll` preference has been removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333714).
Since then, this bug has been [under discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1621570), where a patch has been suggested — this would involve recompiling Firefox from scratch.

As the *“`clickSelectsAll` doesn’t work”* duplicates accumulate on Bugzilla, one of these has received a [comment by Stephen McCarthy](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1643973#c6) which describes a workaround that involves editing internal Firefox files, specifically the `omni.ja` which basically is a `zip` file that contains lots of internal files, e.g. JavaScript modules for the browser chrome, including the relevant `modules/UrlbarInput.jsm`.
This workaround looks like the simplest approach, but the approach doesn’t work as-is.

There is an [official documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_(formerly_omni.jar)) ([archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20210620190432/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_(formerly_omni.jar))) that describes how `omni.ja` should be repackaged.
I also found a [blog article on *Shallow Thoughts*](https://shallowsky.com/blog/tech/web/modifying-omni.ja.html) about modifying `omni.ja` that describes this process in more detail.
Then, there is another thing to worry about: you need to force Firefox to use the modified `omni.ja` by clearing its startup cache, which is explained in an [*In Pursuit Of Laziness* blog article](https://inpursuitoflaziness.blogspot.com/2014/01/editing-files-from-omnija-in-firefox-20.html) that I found.

### Modifying internal files

Puttng all these resources together, these are the shell commands that currently work on Arch Linux (`core/linux` `5.8.1.arch1-1` through `5.12.13.arch1-2`).<sup>1</sup>
If at any point you run into “permission denied” errors, simply continue executing the commands as root.
These need to be executed after every Firefox update.
The commands are explained afterwards.

**Instead of typing the individual commands, you can use this shell script instead, available on this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/SebastianSimon/firefox-omni-tweaks) of mine.**
That script offers a user-friendly terminal interface; it automatically finds Firefox, changes the `omni.ja`, and handles the cache.
It also automatically switches to root as needed and creates backups.
And there’s a [web interface](https://sebastiansimon.github.io/firefox-omni-tweaks) where you can pick other options and download a customized shell script.

#### The commands

```sh
urlbarinput_path=omni/modules/UrlbarInput.sys.mjs

cd /tmp
mkdir omni
unzip -d omni -q /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja

if [[ ! -f /tmp/$urlbarinput_path ]]; then
  urlbarinput_path=omni/modules/UrlbarInput.jsm
fi

sed -i 's/this\._preventClickSelectsAll = this\.focused;/this._preventClickSelectsAll = true;/' $urlbarinput_path
sed -i 's/this\._preventClickSelectsAll = this\._textbox\.focused;/this._preventClickSelectsAll = true;/' omni/chrome/browser/content/browser/search/searchbar.js
cd omni
zip -0DXqr omni.ja *
cd ..
mv omni/omni.ja /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
chown ⟨user⟩:⟨group⟩ /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
rm -r omni
```

Important notes:

- Update Firefox and then close it before doing this.
  Firefox needs to have the updates *installed* (i.e. you may have to start Firefox after upgrading, then close it again).
- `/usr/lib/firefox` is *a possible* install path for Firefox; your path may differ, e.g. it may be `/usr/share/firefox`.
  You should be able to find the possible paths with one of these commands:

  ```sh
  whereis -b firefox firefox-esr
  which firefox firefox-esr
  ```

  The correct `omni.ja` is in the `…/browser/omni.ja` path.
- Before any of this is executed make sure you **create a copy of the working `omni.ja`** somewhere, so you have a backup available in case something goes wrong.
- Make sure you replace `⟨user⟩` by the user name and `⟨group⟩` by the user group of the original ownership of the file.
  As far as I know, in most cases, this should be `root:root`, if it isn’t already.
- After unzipping `omni.ja` you may want to double check that

  - the line `this._preventClickSelectsAll = this.focused;` exists in `modules/UrlbarInput.jsm`, and
  - the line `this._preventClickSelectsAll = this._textbox.focused;` exists in `chrome/browser/content/browser/search/searchbar.js`.

#### Clearing the cache

Finally, Firefox needs to properly load the new `omni.ja` by purging the cache.
These are the two different options I found easiest.
Only one of the options is necessary.

- One way to do that is to simply create an empty file named `.purgecaches` in the `browser` directory.
  For example, you can execute this:

  ```sh
  touch /usr/lib/firefox/browser/.purgecaches
  ```

  You’ll only need to create that file after running the above commands.
  On startup, Firefox will clear its startup cache if it finds this file, and it will also attempt to remove the file.
  Depending on how you originally installed Firefox, removing the file automatically may fail.
  Even if that doesn’t affect successfully clearing the cache, just be aware of that.
- An alternative way is to find the desktop configuration file for Firefox.
  Look into `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` and find some `*.desktop` file with `firefox` (or `nightly` or maybe `mozilla` or something similar) in the file name.
  Open the files you found.
  On my system there are two of them:

  - A small one that starts `firefox-bin` (via `Exec=`)
  - A large one that has three references to `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`

  You want to modify the larger one: after each `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` (or whichever path it is for you) put the `-purgecaches` option (`--purgecaches` works, too); so one of the configuration entries may looke like this:

  ```
  Exec=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -purgecaches %u
  ```

  Using this approach, you [may need to edit your `*.desktop` file after every Firefox update](https://github.com/SebastianSimon/firefox-omni-tweaks/issues/1) and it slows down every start-up of Firefox.

*Now* you can start Firefox by clicking on the desktop icon.

There are two other alternatives, if you don’t start Firefox from clicking on the desktop icon, but instead use the terminal:

- You can type `firefox -purgecaches` into the terminal,
- or you can type `export MOZ_PURGE_CACHES=1` into the terminal, then type `firefox` into the same terminal.

And finally, you can clear the cache directly, as well.
The script caches, including the startup cache, are hidden in the `.cache` directory of your `/home`.
The path will look something like `/home/⟨user⟩/.cache/mozilla/firefox/⟨profileID⟩.⟨profileType⟩/startupCache`.
Deleting these directories will clear the startup cache of Firefox.

Use this approach if you use more than one profile on the same Firefox installation.
The other built-in `purgecaches` approaches only clear the cache of the *first* profile that gets used by Firefox.

#### Explanation

1. This is a variable storing the path of one of the relevant files.
   Later, you need to check if this path exists, because Mozilla has renamed this file around release version 103.

   ```sh
   urlbarinput_path=omni/modules/UrlbarInput.sys.mjs

   # …

   if [[ ! -f /tmp/$urlbarinput_path ]]; then
     urlbarinput_path=omni/modules/UrlbarInput.jsm
   fi
   ```
2. These lines unpack the `omni.ja` file (a quasi PKZIP file) into the newly created `/tmp/omni` directory using the `unzip` utility (`extra/unzip` `6.0-14`)<sup>1</sup>.

   ```sh
   cd /tmp
   mkdir omni
   unzip -d omni -q /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
   ```

   `-d omni` just extracts the files from `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja` into the `/tmp/omni` directory; `-q` suppresses output (just a list of files being inflated and extracted).

   `unzip` will likely exit with status `2` and you’ll get a warning and an error like this when running the `unzip` command:

   ```
   warning [omni.ja]:  50008544 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile (attempting to process anyway)
   error [omni.ja]:  reported length of central directory is -50008544 bytes too long (Atari STZip zipfile?  J.H.Holm ZIPSPLIT 1.1 zipfile?).  Compensating...
   ```

   Don’t worry about it.
   This doesn’t affect the process; status `2` just means that some error was detected, but *“[p]rocessing may have completed successfully anyway”*, as the man page says.
3. Next, these two lines edit the appropriate files in-place.
   The `_preventClickSelectsAll` property controls if selection happens on a single click. Setting it to `true` will prevent this behavior. The first line addresses the URL bar, the second line addresses the search bar.

   ```sh
   sed -i 's/this\._preventClickSelectsAll = this\.focused;/this._preventClickSelectsAll = true;/' $urlbarinput_path
   sed -i 's/this\._preventClickSelectsAll = this\._textbox\.focused;/this._preventClickSelectsAll = true;/' omni/chrome/browser/content/browser/search/searchbar.js
   ```
4. This creates a new `omni.ja` with the changed file using the `zip` utility (`extra/zip` `3.0-9`)<sup>1</sup>.

   ```sh
   cd omni
   zip -0DXqr omni.ja *
   cd ..
   ```

   It’s important to target `*` (every file) inside `omni/`, not the `omni/` directory itself; we don’t want to create an `omni.ja` with `omni` as the root directory.
   Getting in and out of the directory with `cd` also ensures the correct file hierarchy, otherwise, `zip` would still include the additional `omni` root directory in the archive.

   As for the options, `-0` sets the compression level to *no compression* and simply stores the files; `-D` avoids creating entries in the zip archive for directories; `-X` does not save extra file attributes; `-q`, again, suppresses output; `-r` ensures that files are added recursively in their correct directory paths.

   These are the options recommended in the MDN documentation.
   You may have seen an [older revision (before I edited it)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200619234104/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29) that uses `-9` (`-qr9XD`, exactly) instead of `-0`, but this causes issues: for instance, the localization of the tooltips that display keyboard shortcuts fails to load within the developer tools.
   The answer at [Possible to modify hardcoded Firefox JavaScript Ctrl-Tab panel behavior?](https://superuser.com/a/1547335/751213) mentions that `-0` is the `zip` option that creates an `omni.ja` file with a file size closer to the original file.
   Incidentally, that’s the only option that avoids this weird localization issue.
   I explain this in detail in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/SebastianSimon/firefox-omni-tweaks/issues/2).
5. Next, the created `omni.ja` is moved to the Firefox `browser` directory (and it replaces the file; don’t directly use an existing `omni.ja` as the `zip` target, or else the files will be nested into the existing ZIP), the permissions can be set like the original file, and in the end you can remove the `/tmp/omni` directory.

   ```sh
   mv omni/omni.ja /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
   chown ⟨user⟩:⟨group⟩ /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
   rm -r omni
   ```

   It turns out that the `chown` command may not be strictly necessary, but it ensures that the new `omni.ja` has the same owner as the original file.
   Alternatively, if you copied the original file as a non-root user to a backup directory, you can use this:

   ```sh
   chown --reference=⟨your_backup_directory⟩/omni.ja /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
   chmod --reference=⟨your_backup_directory⟩/omni.ja /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
   ```

   Of course, you can use another file, like `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/crashreporter-override.ini` as a reference.

### Restoring an `omni.ja` backup in case something goes wrong

If Firefox doesn’t seem to be running correctly after this process, or not at all, this process didn’t work, unfortunately. You can restore your backup by a simple `mv` like this (possibly as root):

```sh
mv ⟨your_backup_directory⟩/omni.ja ⟨your_firefox_browser_directory⟩/omni.ja
```

Remember to purge the caches once again.

If you didn’t create an `omni.ja` before, you need to [re-download Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-release) and extract the package to find a replacement `omni.ja`.

---

As an aside, the suggested workaround on Bugzilla has a `zip --update` command. The full commands would be:

```sh
unzip -q /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja $urlbarinput_path chrome/browser/content/browser/search/searchbar.js -d omni
# Instead of
# unzip -q /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -d omni
```

… and …

```sh
zip -qr9XDu /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja *
# Instead of
# zip -qr9XD omni.ja *
# mv omni/omni.ja /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
# chown ⟨username⟩:users /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
```

Unfortunately, even with the knowledge about [`zip` file hierarchy](https://askubuntu.com/q/216057/392027), I can’t get this to work — it would be nice, though, as it would speed up the process a bit.
Instead, I get an error like this when starting Firefox:

```
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml
Line Number 740, Column 15:
              <toolbarbutton id="UITourTooltipClose" class="close-icon"
--------------^
```

I wonder if Mozilla automatically reports such errors even if I tampered with the build…

---

### Related questions:

- [change selection behaviour of windows address bar](https://superuser.com/q/729798/751213)
- [How to turn off Firefox address bar auto-selection on focus](https://superuser.com/q/74338/751213)
- [How to not select the whole text of input when return to focus in Firefox](https://superuser.com/q/1273088/751213)

---

<sup>1</sup>: I haven’t tested *all* versions, but this should continue to work for later versions, most earlier versions, and it should work on all release channels of Firefox — after the behavior change of March 2020.

Comment: Thank you! 

The corresponding commands I used on Linux Mint are (sorry, no line breaks in comments):

cd /tmp; 
mkdir omni; 
unzip -q /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -d omni; 
sed -i 's/this\._preventClickSelectsAll = this\.focused;/this._preventClickSelectsAll = true;/' omni/modules/UrlbarInput.jsm; 
sed -i 's/this\._preventClickSelectsAll = this\._textbox\.focused;/this._preventClickSelectsAll = true;/'  omni/chrome/browser/content/browser/search/searchbar.js; 
cd omni; 
zip -qr9XD omni.ja *; 
sudo cp omni.ja /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja; 
firefox --purgecaches;

Comment: @Moini Looks like only the path was different (I changed the example path in the answer to the most common one) and you called `firefox` directly from terminal with `--purgecaches`. Do check out the linked shell script and the edits made to this answer. The script should provide a unified solution with improved usability. I’d like to hear if my script works with other Linux distros and software setups.

Comment: Works on Windows as well (though it's inconvenient that I had to setup a virtual machine with Linux just to perform `zip` / `unzip` commands.

Comment: @izogfif Personally, I like to use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on Windows. There's less overhead.

Comment: This method also works with FirefoxPortable to modify Enterprise policies in `modules/EnterprisePolicies.sys.mjs`. Don't ask me why a portable version needs to consult the registry, for me a portable version of Firefox should not access anything outside of its directory tree.

Comment: It's been 10years! i just opened a ticket to revise this change on firefox, and wrongly said it was 4. :)  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1849593

Comment: @gcb What's strange is that I think firefox nightly for android doesn't do this but desktop does which to me, seems completely backwards. If anything, the android URL bar is more convenient to auto select whereas on PC, there's a standardized number of clicks for insert (one click), select word (two clicks), and select all (three clicks). Even more asinine is that it's now one click = select all, two clicks = select word, three clicks = select all (AGAIN), and four freaking clicks just to insert without selecting. I should sue for carpal tunnel syndrome, there's really no sense to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this behavior as well, but I have a simple workaround.  Move your mouse over the address, **left click** and **drag** to select some text.  Once text has been highlighted you can click anywhere in the string and the cursor will go there.

It becomes second nature and takes no time.

Comment: I already do that when replacing something... but to add something, you now have to select a smaller portion. it's still selecting, unselecting, typing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Opera or Chrome, but in Firefox it's easy enough to open *about:config* and modify the following Boolean values as required:

```
browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll
browser.urlbar.doubleClickSelectsAll
```

Comment: This is obsolete since around March 2020.

Comment: This does not work anymore: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1621570.