# change selection behaviour of windows address bar

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, windows-explorer, address-bar

Is there any way to change the behaviour of address bars in windows (especially in web browsers such as Chrome and Firefox) such that a single click will place the cursor, and a double click will select everything? Having recently returned to windows for work after many happy years of linux and mac usage, this is proving to be one of the more significant irritations.

Comment: I’m not quite sure about what kinds of questions are on-topic on SU, but it appears that this question is too broad since it asks about multiple browsers. Furthermore, it should probably be closed as a duplicate of [go back to NOT selecting the whole URL when i click the address bar](https://superuser.com/q/540851/751213), where I’ve addressed an approach for Firefox.

Comment: see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1849593

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox you can do the following.

1. Open firefox and type `about:config` in the addressbar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It'll confirm, click on *I'll be careful, I promise!* button.
2. Now type `SelectsAll` in the Filter box. It'll show *2 entries*:

   > `browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll`
   >
   > `browser.urlbar.doubleClickSelectsAll`

   `clickSelectsAll` would be set to **false** and `doubleClickSelectsAll` would be set to **true**.

   [image]

---

You could also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> *+* <kbd>L</kbd>(*works in Firefox, Chrome and in the address bar of windows*) to achieve this.