# Possible to modify hardcoded Firefox JavaScript Ctrl-Tab panel behavior?

Tags: firefox, javascript

In the [source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/base/content/browser-ctrlTab.js#120) for the Firefox <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior there's a hardcoded limit of 6 tabs:

```
/**
 * Ctrl-Tab panel
 */
var ctrlTab = {
  maxTabPreviews: 6,
  //...
    for (let i = 0; i < this.maxTabPreviews; i++) {
      previewsContainer.appendChild(this.makePreview(false));
    }
  //...
```

That’s not a lot. Is there any way apart from doing a complete build from source to alter this behavior?

I'm not looking for a workaround or add-on which can present an alternative list of tabs for instance, I really want to find out if there s a way which essentially has the same effect as putting `maxTabPreviews = 10` but without having to compile a custom version of Firefox. Like userchrom.css which can override certain style elements, but then something which allows overridinng this piece of code.

Comment: Hmmm… Good question. But I think the purpose of add-ons is to allow you to override things like this. I could not find one single tab that directly addresses this issue, but I would recommend trying to find something on [Firefox’s official add-on site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=Tab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning** solution presented below works for me without flaws as far as I can tell, but YMMV so try at own risk.

Thanks harrymc for putting me on the way. Your comment saying the string is nowhere in Firefox made me think it's indeed not possible that all .js files from the source are in firefox.exe because it's way to small for that. So I went looking in the application directory for where they are instead and found they are compressed in a single [omni.ja file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29). Unzipping the file using

`unzip omni.ja -d omni`

gives a directory structure with all JavaScript/HTML/CSS etc amongst which there's `omni/chrome/browser/content/browser/browser-ctrlTab.js`. Yay! So I edited the file to use 8 instead of 6, then zipped again as instructed using

```
cd omni
zip -qr9XD omni.ja *
```

The resulting file is however about 2.5 times smaller than the original so I assume firefox doesn't use `9` as compression level these days but `0`. Indeed

```
zip -qr0XD omni.ja *
```

produces a file almost the exact same size as the original. Testing the original omni.ja with 7zip does say 'Warnings: There are some data after the end of the payload data' so that might be the culprit.

Anwyay replacing the original omni.ja with the new one, using `firefox -p` to launch with a new profile just to be safe, I'm delighted to see there are now indeed 8 tabs. Repeated the same again using 12 tabs, screenshot:

[image]

Drawback is obvious: this process likely needs to be repeated after each update. But unless add-ons have access to all internals (which is the next thing to investiagte) it it likely the only way. Improvement would be to render multiple rows instead of one.

Comment: +1 Good job you did there.

Comment: I tried this approach myself and firefox never picked up my changes to omni.ja.  I suspect it will only ever work if you're willing to scrap your profile every time a new version is released, as there is some sort of caching going on.

Comment: @GDorn hmm looks you're right; I didn't notice this yet. When I wrote this answer I actually had my default profile running with 8 tabs without problems. Now, t least 2 updates later, I applied the changes again and indeed I still only have 6. Couldn't find anything which looks like cache for it (at first sight), could also be possible the code changed and something interferes with the number of previews. Will look into it.

Comment: _“The resulting file is however about 2.5 times smaller than the original so **I assume firefox doesn't use 9 as compression level these days but 0**.”_ — after several weeks of research, it looks like I’ve found the solution to a recent bug that I describe [in an issue on a script of mine that repacks `omni.ja`](https://github.com/SebastianSimon/firefox-selection-fix/issues/2). I’ll document that everywhere, including [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29), as soon as I confirm that it actually works after using it for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

This was raised in bug report 3 years ago:
[more than six thumbnails needed when Ctrl+Tab is used](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418178),
and was lately relegated to low priority.

You would need to try an add-on for a solution. Below is a list of
possible add-ons.
I haven't tried them, so cannot tell which one may help solve the problem:

- [Switch To Previous Active Tab & Reload All Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switch-to-previous-active-tab/)
- [Saka](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saka/)
- [Fast Tab Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fast-tab-switcher/)
- [Tip Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tip-tab/)
- [Tab Manager Plus for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-manager-plus-for-firefox/)

Comment: Appreciate the effort you took finding the links, but see edit on the question: I'm not looking for a workaround, I really want to know how to modify or override the built-in functionality.

Comment: You will need to compile Firefox from source. It's possible to find instructions for doing so for your operating system. However, it's not always simple to duplicate the environment in which Firefox was compiled by the developer(s). I can find the instructions for you, but then you are on your own.

Comment: Sure, if the definitive answer is 'there is no way to alter maxTabPreviews or override the ctrlTab function' then I'll take that as answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the answer. The C structure you found has been compiled into the binary. In the best case, the field `maxTabPreviews` resides somewhere inside it and can be patched to another value than 6. In the worst case it has been optimized by the compiler into something else. Locating the byte containing the `6` is possible, but there will be many of them, requiring probably disassembling Firefox into machine-code and hacking. It's a hard job to do.

Comment: Note that the source code shown is written in JavaScript, not C, which is why I was thinking there's may be an easier way. I mean if that file is included as-is with Firefox (eventually compressed or so, doesn't really matter) and that JS code is executed at runtime maybe there's a way to alter it.

Comment: I used a hex editor to search for the string "ctrlTab" in `firefox.exe` and didn't find it. More hacking is always possible, but is too much work.

Comment: Ok that put me on the right track, see my answer.