# How to not select the whole text of input when return to focus in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Is there an option to disable the whole text selection of input in Firefox when I change the application and return back. Example :

[image]

Notice that the search bar selects the whole text when I change to another Firefox screen and return.

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of [change selection behaviour of windows address bar](https://superuser.com/q/74338/751213). There’s a closely related issue about the _click_ behavior which I addressed here: [go back to NOT selecting the whole URL when i click the address bar](https://superuser.com/a/1559926/751213).

Comment: see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1849593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be disabled.  Access the advanced settings by typing `about:config` in the address bar.  Then search for the setting `browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll`.  Double click this value to change it from the default setting of **true** to the "user set" setting of **false** and the URL bar will immediately stop selecting the entire text upon clicking.

Comment: I would like to upvote you but I don't have enough reputation :D

Comment: Quick update this is no longer working.

Comment: @Avtontom_ Is this in the new Firefox (update 57 or later)?  I have the ESR version and it still works there.  Did the setting go away, or just doesn't work any more?

Comment: version 58. The setting is still there and it is still "false". It just doesn't work any more